# How to write an inline function that returns a string?

Tags: dart, flutter

Say I have a silly function that returns a string:

```
String oddMicrosecond() {
  if (DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch%2==0) {
    return "we're even";
  } else {
    return "that's odd";
  }
}

Text(oddMicrosecond());
```

Would it be possible to write that as an anonymous function inline in the `Text` declaration without defining it separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a function for that

```
Text(DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch%2==0 ? "that's odd" : "we're even")
```

you can though

```
Text(() {
    if (DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch%2==0) {
      return "we're even";
    } else {
      return "that's odd";
    }
  }();
)
```

Comment: It's just an example, I _want_ a function for that... for reasons.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I tried that except I didn't put the parentheses at the end and so I wasted an hour thanks to the cryptic useless error message... and my noobish ignorance. But for real who writes those error messages? `The argument type '() → String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'` instead of `You forgot to put '()' at the end.`

Comment: The compiler can't know what your intention was. The error says (at least when you used to Dart ;-) ) that a function that takes no parameters and returns a string can't be passed to a parameter that expects a `String`. If you read it that way it should become quite clear that the mistake is passing a function reference instead of a function call - missing `()`